# Issue importing iOS crash report into Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, symbolicate

I am trying to find an issue from an Apple generated crash report

I have the `dSYM` and the `.app` files in the **Xcode** **Organizer**, but can´t import the `.crash` to resymbolicate it using **Xcode**

The issue is that the "**Import**" and "**Re-Symbolicate**" buttons are absent in the "**Devices View**" and in the "**View Device Logs**" in Xcode 6.1

I have checked the Xcode release noted, but could´t find a reference to this.

I am missing something here?... thx....

Comment: Any solution on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using xcode 6.1.1, so I'm not sure if this was the case in 6.1...

Instead of a "Re-Symbolicate" button, you now need to view the log in the devices window and Control-click on the log name in the list of logs.  This gives you a popup window that lets you delete, export, or re-symbolicate the log.

Unfortunately, though I found the "Re-Symbolicate" menu option, choosing it seems to have no effect and silently fails on the crash log I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Did you find any option other option to re-symbolicate, as I am too unable to symbolicate the logs files, even though I have all the build files archived as necessary

Answer (score 1):

Did you try right clicking on the crash rows in device logs? 
[image]